# что за ошибка и как исправлять?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder, c++11

читал информацию на англ то как то не очень дошло
L"Buffer is too small" && 0
что это? и как исправить?
c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Dovidnyk
{
    char* name;
    int number;
};

void Add(Dovidnyk*&, int&);

void main()
{
    Dovidnyk* dov = NULL;
    int size = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Add(dov, size);
    }
}
void Add(Dovidnyk*& dov, int& size)
{
    if (dov == NULL)
    {
        dov = new Dovidnyk[size + 1];
        cout << "name?" << endl;
        char* tmp = new char[40];
        cin.getline(tmp, 40);
        dov[size].name = new char[strlen(tmp) + 1];
        strcpy_s(dov[size].name, strlen(tmp), tmp);
        cout << "number?" << endl;
        cin >> dov[size].number;
        cin.get();
    }
    else
    {
        Dovidnyk* tmp = new Dovidnyk[size + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            tmp[i].name = new char[strlen(dov[i].name) + 1];
            strcpy_s(tmp[i].name, strlen(dov[i].name), dov[i].name);
            tmp[i].number = dov[i].number;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            delete[]dov[i].name;
        }

        delete[]dov;
        char* tmp2 = new char[20];
        cout << "name?" << endl;
        cin.getline(tmp2, 20);
        tmp[size].name = new char[strlen(tmp2) + 1];
        strcpy_s(tmp[size].name, strlen(tmp2) + 1, tmp2);
        dov = tmp;
        cout << "number?" << endl;
        cin >> dov[size].number;
    }

    size++;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << dov[i].name << "\t" << dov[i].number << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сколько оперативки? не хватает памяти для копирования в буфер обмена?

Comment: @Kryshtop 8gb)))точно должно хватить))это консольное приложение должно было быть. там только одна структура, несколько функций

Comment: Что за информация? Откуда? Что-то очень напоминает этим вот && - какой-то assert...

Comment: @Harry из вижуал студио. при выполении выкакивает окно с ошибкой

Comment: @anonimys при выполнении чего возникает эта ошибка?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов при выполнении консольного приложения после ввода первого значения. а в другой программе точно то же самое только там уже после нескольких этапов выполнения

Comment: @anonimys а у меня вот в консольных программах так не бывает. Ваша программа падает - давайте исходники. Не ваша - в ней где-то ошибка и без ее изменения не исправить.

Comment: @anonimys  Приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов добавил. смотрите код

Comment: @VladfromMoscow добавил. смотрите код

Comment: @anonimys запускайте под отладчиком и смотрите где падает.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов делал - не показывает, просто ошибка и все

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да все просто...
При вызове `strcpy_s` указывается размер буфера, а вы указываете длину строки. Вот и получаете...

Попробуйте так -

```
    dov[size].name = new char[strlen(tmp) + 1];
    strcpy_s(dov[size].name, strlen(tmp)+1, tmp);

    tmp[i].name = new char[strlen(dov[i].name) + 1];
    strcpy_s(tmp[i].name, strlen(dov[i].name)+1, dov[i].name);
```

Только учите, что это еще далеко не все. Например, у вас утечка памяти есть - `tmp` вы память выделяете и не удаляете...